# Apache Jmeter JDBC Request

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, jmeter

In a JDBC request with jmeter to a postgres db is it possible to limit the number of results returned by a query (without adding the limit to the query itself).

Ex: End the test when i get 50 results from that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler - no, unfortunately.

You can use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a workaround and build your request manually using [Java JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/)

Assuming you will have the full control, you will be able to use [Statement.setMaxRows()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-) function in order to limit the result set to the desired size.

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) in JMeter scripts.